# java - sorting a hashmap with date inside value object

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, date-sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Suppose am having a map like

```
Map<String, Student> studDetails = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

And the map contains entries like

```
studDetails.put("1",student1);
studDetails.put("2",student2);
studDetails.put("3",student3);
studDetails.put("4",student4);
```

Student entity is Something like

```
Class Student{
           private String studName;
           private List<Group> groups;
}
```

Group entity will be like

```
Class Group{
             private String groupName;
             private Date creationDate;
}
```

OK, so what I need is when am displaying student details, it will be in the order of group creation date.
So if student is mapped to more than one group, we can take the creationDate of first group.

How can I given the soring on my HashMap `studDetails` using this scenario.?

Can anyone help..please..

Comment: Sorting a map based on the values is achieved here: [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java). Moreover, `Date` is `Comparable`, so you shouldn't have a hard time figuring out how to utilize this ;)

Answer (score 4):

HashMap is not sorted you should use a `SortedMap` implementation instead for example [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Then you could create your own [`Comparator<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which will sort by the `groups` attribute of the actual `Student` instance but you'll need the actual map for it because `TreeMap` **sorts by the keys**, so this is a possible but not nice solution.

So with `TreeMap`:

```
public class StudentGroupComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  private Map<String, Student> sourceMap;

  public StudentGroupComparator(Map<String, Student> sourceMap) {
    this.sourceMap = sourceMap;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
    // TODO: null checks
    Student student1 = sourceMap.get(key1);
    Student student2 = sourceMap.get(key2);

    Date o1CreationDate = student1.groups.get().creationDate;
    Date o2CreationDate = student2.groups.get().creationDate;
    return o1CreationDate.compareTo(o2.creationDate);
  }
}


SortedMap<String, Student> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Student>(new StudentGroupComparator(sourceMap));
sortedMap.putAll(sourceMap);
```

Comment: `Comparator<Student>` won't help: the `Student` is the value, not the key.

Comment: Not true! It depends on your implementation.

Comment: You linked to a `TreeMap`.  If you could replace that with a link to a `Map` that sorts by value, I'd be happy to remove my -1.

Comment: @DavidGrant Using a custom comparator, you can sort a `TreeMap` by value. See the link in the comment to the question.

Comment: This won't compile.  For `TreeMap<K,V>`, you must provide a `Comparator<K>`.

Comment: @Baz that's nice :)  However, this answer isn't giving the same advice.

Comment: @DavidGrant Your second comment sounded like you would imply this isn't possible with a treemap. But maybe I misunderstood that.

Comment: @Baz I think using a comparator of type `K` that has implicit knowledge of how to compare `V` is probably stretching the implementation a little (although obviously useful).  It'd much more useful to the OP (IMHO) to provide a `Map` implementation which accepted a `Comparator<V>`

Comment: @DavidGrant Thanks, I missed the value part first.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I given the soring on my HashMap studDetails using this scenario?

You can't, because `HashMap` is fundamentally unordered (or at least, the ordering is unstable and unhelpful).

Even for sorted maps like `TreeMap`, the sort order is based on the *key*, not the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Add Students Objects to List and Use `Collections.sort(list, custom_comparetor).`

**Prepare one Custom comparator to sort Students Objects.**

Try this code it might helpful

**StudentComparator.java**

```
class StudentComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object stud1, Object stud2) {
        List<Group> list1Grp = ((Student) stud1).getGroups();
        List<Group> list2Grp = ((Student) stud2).getGroups();

        Collections.sort(list1Grp, new GroupComparator());
        Collections.sort(list2Grp, new GroupComparator());
        return list1Grp.get(0).getCreationDate().compareTo(list2Grp.get(0).getCreationDate());
    }

}
```

**GroupComparator.java**

```
public class GroupComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object grp1, Object grp2) {
        return ((Group) grp1).getCreationDate().compareTo(
                ((Group) grp2).getCreationDate());
    }

}
```

main method

add student object to one new List

then use

```
Collections.sort(new_stud_list, new StudentComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Comparable to Group

```
class Group implements Comparable {
    private String groupName;
    private Date creationDate;

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object t) {
        Group g = (Group) t;
        return getCreationDate().compareTo(g.getCreationDate());
    }
}
```

Use TreeSet instead of List in Student for Groups

```
public class Student implements Comparable {
    private String studName;
    private TreeSet<Group> groups;

    public TreeSet<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object t) {
        Student t1 = (Student) t;
        return groups.first().getCreationDate()
                .compareTo(t1.getGroups().first().getCreationDate());
    }

}
```

Now use

```
TreeSet<Student> studDetails = new TreeSet();
```

then add students. It will be ordered one. Hope you can take care of null pointer exceptions